# Thymleaf adding white space above table for every row in table

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf to iterate through a list and display it in a table like so.

```
<span class="title" th:text="${schema}"> Event List </span>
<table class="table is-fullwidth">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>Payload</th>
        <th>MetaData</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>them
    <tbody>
    <th:block th:each="event :${data}">
        <tr>
            <td th:text="${event.timestamp}"></td>
            <td>
                <pre lang="xml" th:text="${event.payload}"></pre>
            </td>
            <td>
                <pre lang="xml" th:text="${event.metaData}"></pre>
            </td>
            </br>
        </tr>
    </th:block>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

However I have discovered that in both Chrome and IE 
 tags are being inserted above the table. For every row in the table there is a 
 tag above the table in the rendered html. Curiously enough, I don't see the 
 tags when I view the source of the web page, but I see them when I use chrome's developer console.

Here's the output for when the table has three rows.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Events</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div id="navbarBasic" class="navbar-menu">
          <div class="navbar-start">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="/events/A">A</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="/events/B">B</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="/events/C">C</a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="/events/D">D</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <span class="title">B</span>
    <br><br><br>
    <table class="table is-fullwidth">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Timestamp</th>
          <th>Payload</th>
          <th>MetaData</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the output for the table has nine rows:

```html
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Events</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div><nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div id="navbarBasic" class="navbar-menu">
            <div class="navbar-start">
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/events/A">A</a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/events/B">B</a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/events/C">C</a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="/events/D">D</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav></div>
    <span class="title">A</span>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><table class="table is-fullwidth">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
            <th>Payload</th>
            <th>MetaData</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>



</body></html>
```

I have deleted the actual data out of the table rows due to my employer's policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `<br />` in an unexpected spot in your code.  Since it's in an invalid location, Chrome moves it outside the table which is where you get all those extra lines.

```
        <td>
            <pre lang="xml" th:text="${event.metaData}"></pre>
        </td>
        </br> <------------------- what is this for?
    </tr>
</th:block>
```

And some style tips, I think your html should look like this:

```
<table class="table is-fullwidth">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>Payload</th>
        <th>MetaData</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="event :${data}">
        <td th:text="${event.timestamp}"></td>
        <td><pre lang="xml" th:text="${event.payload}" /></td>
        <td><pre lang="xml" th:text="${event.metaData}" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

No need for the `th:block` (just add the `th:each` to the `<tr />`).  I would personally use a closed `<pre />` tag as well.